# How to change the value of a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have this code right here and I want to change as I commented out on my code.
What function is the right one to use in this scenario?

```
<span id="value" style="margin: 3px;">
<?php 
  if(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo) < 0){
    echo '<span style="color:#fb3f6c;">'.number(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo))."</span>";
  } elseif(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo) > 0){
    echo '<span style="color:#25804a;">'.number(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo))."</span>";
  } else {
    echo number(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo)); 
}
?>
</span>                    
<i id="<?php echo $id_forum; ?>" class="vote_up fas fa-angle-up"></i>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("i.vote_up").click(function(){

        var value_no = document.getElementById("value");
        var forum_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("game/forum/vote_post.php",
            {
                forum_id: forum_id,
                type: 0
            },
            function(res, status){
                // Update 'value' and add 1 to 'value_no' without page refresh
            }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Get value like `var value_no = parseInt($("#value").find('span').text())` and then add  `1` to it .

Comment: var value_no = $("#value").children('span').text() to get value of span

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla solution.

```
...
function(res, status) {
  let spanNode = value_no.childNodes[0];
  let newValue = parseInt(spanNode.innerHTML) + 1; // Make sure the text inside span is integer
  spanNode.innerHTML = "New value: " + newValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try with `$("#value").html()` or `$("#value").text()`

```
<span id="value" style="margin: 3px;">
    <?php 
      if(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo) < 0){
        echo '<span style="color:#fb3f6c;">'.number(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo))."</span>";
      } elseif(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo) > 0){
        echo '<span style="color:#25804a;">'.number(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo))."</span>";
      } else {
        echo number(get_forum_likes($id_forum, $pdo)); 
    }
    ?>
    </span>                    
    <i id="<?php echo $id_forum; ?>" class="vote_up fas fa-angle-up"></i>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("i.vote_up").click(function(){

            var value_no = document.getElementById("value");
            var forum_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.post("game/forum/vote_post.php",
                {
                    forum_id: forum_id,
                    type: 0
                },
                function(res, status){
                    $("#value").html();
                    value_no++
                }
            );
        });
    });
    </script>
```